# Dart correct way to specify generic argument type on callback function

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, anonymous-function

I'vo got a strange error, for a class similar to this one:

```dart
class UpdatableListPage<T> extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final StateNotifierProvider<UpdatableNotifier, List<T>> provider;
  final Widget Function(T t) callbackWidget;

[...]

  @override
  _UpdatableListPageState<T> createState() => _UpdatableListPageState<T>();
}


class _UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage> {

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Here the IDE said modelList is dynamic
    var modelList = ref.watch(widget.provider);
    [...]
    ListView(
                key: _refreshKey,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: widget.scrollDirection,
                children: [
                  for (final product in modelList as List<T>) widget.callbackWidget.call(product),
              ],

  }

}
```

And I call the funciton as:

```dart
UpdatableListPage<RsMsgMetaData>(
          userPostsProvider,
          callbackWidget:  (t) => PostTeaserCard(t,),
        ),
```

Where `PostTeaserCard` is a statefull Widget that recieve a `RsMsgMetaData` object as parameter.

The IDE say that everything is Ok but at run time, I got the following error:

```
type '(RsMsgMetaData) => PostTeaserCard' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget'`
```

Seems like `callbackWidget` acts as `(dynamic) => Widget` function, but anyway... Should this function be compatible with the function signature of the anonymous function, right?

I don't know what is going on with this...

Comment: Does changing `_UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage>` to `_UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage<T>>` help? `UpdatableListPage` without an explicit type is shorthand for `UpdatableListPage<dynamic>`, which probably explains how `callbackWidget` becomes a `Widget Function(dynamic)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```dart
class _UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage> {
```

which is equivalent to:

```dart
class _UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage<dynamic>> {
```

Consequently, the type of `_UpdatableListPageState<T>.widget.callbackWidget` is `Widget Function(dynamic t)`.  You cannot pass a `PostTeaserCard Function(RsMsgMetaData)` for a `Widget Function(dynamic)` because the latter is callable with any argument, but the function you actually passed can be called only with an `RsMsgMetaData` argument.

To fix this, fix your `_UpdatableListPageState` class declaration to avoid the implicit use of `dynamic` and to fully depend on `T`:

```dart
class _UpdatableListPageState<T> extends ConsumerState<UpdatableListPage<T>> {
```

This probably will fix the type for `modelList` to `List<T>` instead of `List<dynamic>`.

Enabling the [`strict-raw-types`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) check in your `analysis_options.yaml` should help catch this kind of error in the future.